# cannot use dot operator on a type

Tags: c++

hi so basically i am new to coding and i had this problem with my first class/header program.

(the cartest.cpp is the main and it is not finished just wanted to check how everything is going (spoiler alert not good))

car.hpp

```
class car {
private: 
string carid;
string carName;
double car_capacity ;
double benzinverbrauch;
double _fillLevel;
double _milage;
public:
bool refuel (const double benzinmenge);
double drive (double dist);
double fillLevel();
double reach();
double milage();
};
```

car.cpp

```
#include "car.hpp"


bool car::refuel (double benzinmenge) {
if (benzinmenge+_fillLevel <=car_capacity){
    _fillLevel=benzinmenge+_fillLevel;
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
};
};
 double car::drive (const double dist){
if (reach()<=dist) {
    _fillLevel=0;
    return reach();}
else {
    _fillLevel=_fillLevel-(dist*benzinverbrauch/100);
    return dist;
};
};
double car::reach (){
return (_fillLevel*100)/benzinverbrauch;
};
 double car::fillLevel()
    {return _fillLevel;};

  double car::milage()
    {return _milage;};
```

cartest.cpp

```
#include "car.hpp"

int main(){
double car_capacity=50 ;
double benzinverbrauch=50;
double _fillLevel=0;
car.refuel (20.0);
cout<<car.fillLevel()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a *class* (a type definition)  and an *object*, or an *instance* of that class. Of a given class there is just one definition  but you can create many instances. You haven't created an instance of `car`. E.g. `car c;`

Comment: One more note: There is no semi-colon after else's closing bracket in bool car::refuel() function in the car.cpp file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing @Jonathon Reinhart's comment, Class defined how your objects behave. But you need to have objects to behave that way too. To declare a variable, the syntax is:

```
<Class> <object>
```

For example:

```
car c;
```

To use a function, you need to use the object. The syntax is:

```
<object>.<function>
```

For example:

```
c.refuel(20.0);
```

Comment: Thanks @miken32 I dont know what I was thinking when I wrote it. It was a long time ago. Young blood eh?